# Issues for iscsi setup on Oracle RAC node

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, oracle-rac

I followed [this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-rac11gr2-iscsi-088677.html) to setup Oracle RAC with openfiler.

I did setup Oracle RAC on rac1, rac2 node and openfiler configuration. After this, I followed the following steps from above document:

1. Installed and configured iscsi services.
2. Followed manual and automatic login to iscsi target on rac node:

   ```
   iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl.crs1 -p 10.0.1.39 -l
   iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl.crs1 -p 10.0.1.39 --op update -n node.startup -v automatic
   ```
3. Executed command:

   ```
   cd /dev/disk/by-path; ls -l *openfiler* | awk '{FS=" "; print $9 " " $10 " " $11}'`
   ```

   got below output:

   ```
   ip-10.0.0.29:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-crs1-lun-0 -> ../../sdf
   ip-10.0.0.29:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-data1-lun-0 -> ../../sdj
   ip-10.0.0.29:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-fra1-lun-0 -> ../../sdh
   ip-10.0.1.39:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-crs1-lun-0 -> ../../sdg
   ip-10.0.1.39:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-data1-lun-0 -> ../../sdk
   ip-10.0.1.39:3260-iscsi-iqn.2006-01.com.openfiler:orcl-fra1-lun-0 -> ../../sdi
   ```
4. Created following rules in **/etc/udev/rules.d/55-openiscsi.rules** file:

   ```
   KERNEL=="sd*", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/scripts/iscsidev.sh %b",SYMLINK+="iscsi/%c/part%n"
   ```
5. Next, created the UNIX shell script /etc/udev/scripts/iscsidev.sh as below:

   ```
   BUS=${1}
   HOST=${BUS%%:*}
   [ -e /sys/class/iscsi_host ] || exit 1

   file="/sys/class/iscsi_host/host${HOST}/device/session*/iscsi_session*/targetname"
   target_name=$(cat ${file})

   if [ -z "${target_name}" ]; then
      exit 1
   fi

   echo "${target_name##*.}"
   ```

   After creating the UNIX SHELL script, changed it to executable:

   ```
   chmod 755 /etc/udev/scripts/iscsidev.sh
   ```
6. Restarted the iSCSI service.
7. Executed command `ls -l /dev/iscsi/*` then got error as below:

   ```
   ls: cannot access /dev/iscsi/*: No such file or directory
   ```

Any idea on this?